# How to execute a command using a line from a text file?

Tags: bash

I have a file with several paths to other files.

```
/root/Desktop/test1/test2/f1
/root/Desktop/test1/test2/f2
```

I need to execute a command from the terminal to delete f1 and f2 by importing their paths from that file.

Something like "rm code"

code = line 1 of the file text

Is there a way to do so ?

Answer (score -1):

```
rm root/Desktop/test1/test2/f*
```

should do if I understood your question.

Comment: I need to import that line automatically from the file which contains that path and not paste it manually.